# Using Azure Devops as repository for external npm and nuget packages

Tags: npm, azure-devops, nuget, repository

Can't find a simple way to move hundreds of npm and nuget packages from Nexus 2 to on prem Azure Devops server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate the source code repositories of the npm and NuGet packages from Nexus 2 to Azure Repos, you can use the [**Import repository**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops) feature to import each of the repositories from Nexus 2 to Azure Repos.

[image]

If you want to migrate the published packages from Nexus 2 to Azure Artifacts.

- For NuGet packages, you can reference the document "[**Migrate NuGet packages to Azure Artifacts**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/migrate-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)" to use the **`AzureArtifactsPackageMigration`** PowerShell module to migrate your NuGet packages to Azure Artifacts.
- For the npm packages, since the **`AzureArtifactsPackageMigration`** PowerShell module only supports migrating NuGet packages currently, and we do not have other tools can be available, you may need to manually publish your npm packages to Azure Artifacts (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/publish?view=azure-devops)).